# how a child can get the width / height of it's parent dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

let's say I have a `ChildWidget()` and `ParentWidget()` and I want to say something like :

- however, the parent width is, the child's width should be 20% of it

example :
if a parent has a `width: 200`, the child's width should be `width: 40`.

and I want a way that's dynamic and not actually hardcoded values, so I will change the parent width and expect that the child

any ideas are welcome.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html - the docs say: "A widget that sizes its child to a fraction of the total available space"

Comment: use layout builder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pskink mentioned, `FractionallySizedBox` is handy in your case.

```dart
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 400,
          height: 400,
          color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.2, //20% width
            heightFactor: .5, //50% height
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Also, you can check eamirho3ein's answer on LayoutBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your parent widget is this `container`:

```
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 300,
),
```

you can do this to get its size:

```
Container(
   height: 200,
   width: 300,
   color: Colors.red,
   alignment: Alignment.center, // very important part is set alignment
   child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Container( 
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.2,
          height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.3,
      );
    },),
),
```

**result**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should use the MediaQuery class like in the next example :

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .20
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .20
```

this will give the width and the height for the parent child * 20%

- for getting the width and height of the parent widget you could use this way : you can put the child widget in a LayoutBuilder widget , this widget will allow you to get the parent width and height , and this is an example about this :

  ```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("screen width ${MediaQuery.of(context).size.width}");
    debugPrint("screen height ${MediaQuery.of(context).size.height}");
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black,border: Border.all(color: Colors.red,width: 5)),
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  return SizedBox(
                      width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.50,
                      height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.50 ,
                      child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text("stack overflow")));
                },
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

try to run this build method and you will understand the example.

Comment: thanks, but this set a width / height based on the screen, not a parent widget.

Comment: ok bro I got you , I will edit the answer and add the wanted code.